# Reshaping Data in R with Reshape

Tags: r, reshape

I have this dataset and for the life of me, I couldn't figure out how to get it in the format I want. I know that I needed to use `melt` from `reshape` package and possibly do a bit of `transpose`...

Would appreciate any help! Thank you!

**Reproducible Data**

```
df <- data.frame("Date" = c("jun", "aug", "dec"), 
                 "A1" = c("1", "3", "5"),
                 "A2" = c(10,11,12))

  Date A1 A2
1  jun  1 10
2  aug  3 11
3  dec  5 12
```

**Intended Output**

```
  Date Category Amt
1  jun       A1   1
2  aug       A1   3
3  dec       A1   5
4  jun       A2  10
5  aug       A2  11
6  dec       A2  12
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `gather` to reshape from 'wide' to 'long' format.  Specify the names of the 'key', 'value' column as 'Category', 'Amt' and the columnsto reshape with one of the `select_helpers` `matches` which will do a regex matching by checking the names that start (`^`) with 'A' followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   gather(Category, Amt, matches("^A\\d+$"))
#   Date Category Amt
#1  jun       A1   1
#2  aug       A1   3
#3  dec       A1   5
#4  jun       A2  10
#5  aug       A2  11
#6  dec       A2  12
```

We can also specify the columns with index

```
df %>% 
     gather(Category, Amt, 2:3)
```

---

Or another option is `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = 'Date', value.name = 'Amt', variable.name = 'Category')
```

---

Or using `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(df, idvar = 'Date', direction = 'long', varying = list(2:3))
```

Note: Assuming that the 'A1' column is numeric or character class

Comment: could you explain this part pls? `matches("^A\\d+$")`

Comment: also, is it possible to do it with `melt`?

Comment: @Javier yes, both requests are done